# Android - How to start Facebook Messenger Audio call from within my app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

I already know how to start a Skype Call from within my app using this code:

```
    Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    skypeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + skypeId + "?call"));
    context.startActivity(skypeIntent);
```

I would like to **do the same thing using Messenger app**.

I couldn't find information about that neither in the [Messenger SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android) , nor on the web.

Some related information I found, but no solution:

- I stumbled on [this list of Uris](http://binwaheed.blogspot.fr/2014/06/android-open-facebook-official-app-from.html), but none seems to be related to passing audio calls.
- [how to start android facebook app chat from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971731/how-to-start-android-facebook-app-chat-from-another-app) , but nothing about audio calls.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone...? is it even possible? Thanks.